# What is advantage of using service wrapper in Spring boot instead of jar running?

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, java-service-wrapper

Spring document has mentioned about service wrapper in http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html.

On production, we can use `java -jar [x].jar` to run our application which it's more easier.

What are those advantage to use service wrapper ?

Comment: As a side note, I would recommend Docker: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*What is advantage of using service wrapper in Spring boot instead of jar running?*

If the application should restart automatically when the server reboots because of power failure, hardware failure or some other *temporary* condition then the service approach *primarily* has the advantage that you don't have to login to the machine to start the `jar`. Which is useful if it's production software and 3 am when the janitor pulls the server plug to vacuum.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if application JVM crashes (out of memory, JVM bug, etc...), JSW will restart it.